# The Binded Output is being duplicated

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

so I have a GridView like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
    OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="gv_RowDeleting" Width="100%" 
    OnPreRender="gv_PreRender">
    <Columns>
...
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Temperatura">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox MaxLength="10" ID="gvtxtTemp" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Registro3", "{0} °F")%>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ControlStyle Width="100%" BackColor="Transparent" BorderStyle="None" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So let's say that the value to bind is the number "10", so I would expect the output to be something like "10 °F" but instead I'm getting "10 °F °F". Why? am I doing something wrong?

I also tried doing it in the codebehind but the result was the same.

**Update**: Now I changed the format string to "a {0} °F" and I'm getting "a a 10 ° °F", now what's that suppose to mean?

Comment: What happens when you just do {0}, your not using a user type that already has it's ToString() method overloaded to add the °F on the end are you?

Comment: What do get without the formatting?  Are you sure that your data is returning just 10?

Comment: yes, without the formating I'm getting just 10, same if I just format like "{0}". Any Ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What do you get if you remove the ° character?

Comment: @_rick: If I remove the °, I get "10 F F"... :S

Comment: Come to the conclusion, your ASP.NET install just hates you.

Comment: wait, try 
    `Text=<%# Eval("Registro3", "{0} °F")%>`
instead of
    `Text='<%# Eval("Registro3", "{0} °F")'%>`
(removal of the ' ' around the <%# %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got what I wanted, the format I used was:

```
<asp:TextBox MaxLength="10" ID="gvtxtTemp" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Registro3", "{0:#.# °F}")%>' />
```

and now I'm getting the desired output "10 °F", even thought the data is not a number (It's a varchar(10) field). Why did this work beat's me, but It worked, maybe some of you could tell me the reason. Anyhow thanks all for all your help!

Comment: I didn't wip up a test project to verify, but I was going to suggest, {0: °F} earlier today.